# How to change battery in garage door keypad?

Tags: garage-door-opener, battery

One of the keys on the keypad for my garage door somehow got a key stuck temporarily and drained the battery.  That was easily fixed, but now I am trying to replace the battery. The pictogram seems pretty obvious as to what to do:
[image]
(for searchability it's a LiftMaster.  I don't know the exact model but it's one of 940CB, 976LM, and 376LM as these models apparently share this keypad.)

Just slide the bottom cover down and off and the battery will be underneath, right?  Except that try as I might I can't get the cover to budge! I have tried squeezing on the sides, pressing on the front, and even trying to wedge a flat head screwdriver on the slot on the sides and/or button while doing any of the above.  I have exerted all the force I dare to not break the plastic in the process!

There is no obvious issue like it being painted over, although the plastic kind of "feels" very slightly brittle, possible due to age.  It normally isn't directly exposed to the sun - it has a cover that flips up, although occasionally somebody forgets to put it back down.

How do I get the bottom cover off so I can change the battery?  Is there some kind of track on where to press or squeeze or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this page](https://support.chamberlaingroup.com/s/article/How-do-I-change-the-battery-in-a-wireless-keypad-1484145657107) which stated:

> The second oldest style keypads have a pin hole at the bottom of the keypad cover. You will have to insert a small Phillips screw driver into the small hole at the bottom of the cover and gently pull outward to loosen and slide the cover down to remove. Below is a picture you can reference.

But strangely, the picture didn't show how the screw driver was to be used.  I wasn't able to get this method to work.

However, I finally found that if I pushed in the center top of the cover I could create a gap wide enough for a normal flat head screwdriver to fit.  I then attempted to rotate the screwdriver to pry the cover away from the main body of the opener and finally heard a loud "pop" as the entire cover moved down about 1/8th of an inch.  I was then able with a bit of work to pry the cover off.  When I put the cover back on, I noticed that there was something of a lip on the top of the cover, meaning that the bottom wanted to swing *in* rather than simply go straight up.

Comment: Pictogram design is astonishingly hard in practice.  Good work finding and sharing your answer.  It might help to put the brand "liftmaster" and any models or model numbers into your question to help future searchers and search engines.

Comment: This is why pictograms so often fail so horribly in comparison to words. Please be sure to give yourself a check-mark for this answer as soon as the system will let you. That will also let others know that it's been resolved and is good to look at for a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull up lift out from the bottom of the piece it has a groove at the top it connects to the top of the bottom to. And has to slide out from under it. It is a tight connection

Answer (score 0):

What had me stumped for a while was not knowing that there are four plastic tabs to be addressed to remove the cover.  There is one small one centered along the bottom edge.  This is accessed by pushing up with a very small Phillips head screwdriver (or, I think any round metal object of small diameter) up through the small hole at the bottom. This will contact a "springy" tab, pushing it up and clearing its slot. Then there are slightly larger tabs centered on each side.  And, finally, a tab at the top that runs the width of the case. Sequence of tab releases:  (1) Release the tab at bottom.  This frees the bottom and the tab at one side; (2) Push the battery cover gently toward the side not yet released.  This will probably take some careful wiggling and nudging to get it to clear the slot; (3) Push in along the top edge of the battery cover and simultaneously pull outward at the bottom. Some evil person designed this crazy arrangement, and then provided no comprehensible and complete instructions!